# How do I save correlation chart to an object?

Tags: r

I'd like to make a correlation plot and save it to an object in a list.

I'm using a function and it appears to run the plot any time the function runs, so it's hard to save it to an object.

I could use record output, but I don't want it to show up at all. This is under the hood in a function, so I want to assign it to an object without having it run.

This is my code

```
library(fpp)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
l <- list()  

l[["element"]] <-
  chart.Correlation(credit, 
                histogram = TRUE, 
                pch = 19)

l$element
```

I want to load the correlation plot when I run l$element, but not when I assign it to l[["element"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little complex, because there is no "plot object". The call to `chart.Correlation` simply calls a bunch of drawing routines. It's not like a `ggplot` where the information to recreate the plot is stored as an object. In fact, the `chart.Correlation` function silently returns `NULL`.

If you want `l$element` to produce the plot, then you need to store the *call* to produce the plot inside `l$element`, and ensure that this call is evaluated when you type `l$element` into the console. Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a little wrapper around `chart.Correlation` with your own S3 class, whose print method `eval`s the call:

```r
library(fpp)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
l <- list()  

make_corrChart <- function(...) {
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1]] <- quote(chart.Correlation)
  structure(list(call = mc), class = "CorrChart")
}

print.CorrChart <- function(x, ...) eval(x$call)

l[["element"]] <-  make_corrChart(credit, histogram = TRUE, pch = 19)
```

Note that no plot is created at this point, but all the information needed to create the plot is stored in `l$element`. So when I type:

```
l$element
```

In the console, I get this:

[image]